# Why is the order of output as is - I would think it has to be otherwise?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, format

```
>>> names = "{1}, {2} and {0}".format('John', 'Bill', 'Sean')
>>> print(names)
Bill, Sean and John
>>> print(type(names))
<class 'str'>
```

I don't understand why the output is `Bill, Sean and John`.

I am confused and thought that it should be `Bill, John and Sean` or `John, Sean and Bill`.

Comment: i am not able get how the output is bill,sean and john ,i am confused that it should be bill,john and sean or john,sean and bill

Comment: Why do you think the output *should* be `2, 1, 0` or `1, 2, 0`, instead of `0, 1, 2`?

Answer (score 2):

The formatting you are doing is *positional*:

```
names = "{1}, {2} and {0}".format('John', 'Bill', 'Sean')
#         1.   2.      0.     <=>    0.     1.      2.
```

`'John'` is provided on position 0, `'Bill'` is provided on position 1 and `'Sean'` is provided on position 2 as parameters given to `.format('John', 'Bill', 'Sean')`.

Hence it prints:

```
Bill, Sean and John
```

See: [str.format documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

> Perform a string formatting operation. The string on which this method is called can contain literal text or replacement fields delimited by braces {}. Each replacement field contains **either the numeric index** of a **positional argument**, or the name of a keyword argument.

Using names instead of position is possible as well:

```
names = "{S}, {B} and {J}".format( J = 'John', B = 'Bill', S = 'Sean')

print(names)
```

prints

```
Sean, Bill and John
```